# Add a uniqueness constraint to a model's named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have this configuration:

```
model Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :toys
  has_many :inventories, :through => :toys

  scope :for_inventory, lambda{ |inv| joins(:toys).where("toys.inventory_id = ?",inv) }
end

model Toy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  belongs_to :inventory
end

model Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :toys
  has_many :boxes, :through => :toys
end
```

Now, here is the worry,

```
Inventory.find(2).boxes.count
>> 140
```

while

```
Box.for_inventory(2).count
>> 506
Box.for_inventory(2).uniq.count
>> 506
```

The thing is that if a `Box` contains multiple `Toys`, it is returned several times.
So, I thought I could override the `<=>` operator for the `Box` class so `.uniq` would actually do something and redduce the list from 506 to 140. But isn't there a better way to change the `Box::for_inventory` scope so it does that at request time?

Comment: you can use `:includes` to get the correct number but that would be slower.

Comment: Compared to overriding the `<=>` operator and using the `.uniq`? What would you advise?

Comment: try the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679793/query-that-joins-child-model-results-item-erroneously-shown-multiple-times